# dynamic data display chartplotter get current axis values

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I am working with d3 chartplotter. In my application, I want the program to automatically detect the current start and end values of my horizontal axis on display. For example, let us say the user zooms in the data plotted. I know the axis value will be automatically adjusted and displayed on the plotter. What I want is (upon a button click maybe), the program should extract what is the start and end value of the X-axis on display at that moment. I need these two values to do some other thing. I am using C# wpf for programming btw. I tried searching for it in forums, but no luck so far.
Here's what I have so far. But not sure how to get any further to achieve my objective.

`CursorCoordinateGraph coordinategraph = new CursorCoordinateGraph();`
`plotter.Children.Add(coordinategraph);`

```
Upon buttonclick()
{ Retrieve the first and last x-coordinate value on display...}
```

Any pointer in the right direction is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. happened to be too simple :)

```
var v = plotter.Visible;
int X_left = Convert.ToInt32(v.Left);
int X_right = Convert.ToInt32(v.Right);
```